# Element with a fixed position won't stay fixed on GoodBarber

Tags: html, css

I am creating an app for a client and am implementing Podium on the app. GoodBarber allows you to make custom pages with Html, but the podium element won't stay fixed. The first script element is the podium button. If you don't know what podium is here is some [documentation](https://docs.podium.com/reference/introduction) and the [website](https://www.podium.com/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script defer src="https://connect.podium.com/widget.js#ORG_TOKEN="hidden" id="podium-widget" data-organization-api-token="hidden"></script>
</style>
</head>
<body>
       ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it would help if you posted some sample code. If we can see what you have attempted, then you are probably more likely to get a better answer

Comment: Gotcha, but the problem is that usually with podium button you can't really customize it with css.

Comment: Your document is invalid. All content must be inside either the head or body elements.

Comment: That was misplacement on my end, but when I moved it didn't make much of a difference. The program doesn't really go by all the elements. If anything it only listens to the body and the head elements